# how to add <span id="data">inside <textarea>

Tags: html

`<textarea class="autoExpand" id="text" name="text" data-min-rows="1" rows="1" cols="50" maxlength="2000" >Y</textarea>`

I am trying to make y a variable in `<span id="data">`

I tried adding span straight in to Y's area but it didn't work

Comment: you would simply be adding a text string rather than a dom element within the textarea. a `textarea` does not allow other elements as children - it only allows text

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by `trying to make y a variable in <span id="data">` - what is the ultimate goal?

Comment: add a random message in the box

Comment: To generate a random message inside the textarea is straightforward - just set the value of the textarea to whatever random text message you want. Note though any HTML in the message will be displayed "as-is" and **not** rendered as HTML